# Configuration of compiled Apache2

Tags: apache-httpd

When installing a module, I noticed the following:

```
ModSecurity for Apache/2.8.0 (http://www.modsecurity.org/) configured.
[Tue Dec 09 19:01:10 2014] [notice] ModSecurity: APR compiled version="1.4.5"; loaded version="1.4.5"
[Tue Dec 09 19:01:10 2014] [notice] ModSecurity: PCRE compiled version="8.2 "; loaded version="8.02 2010-03-19"
```

Is it possible to run a command to see all loaded libraries and also their versions? Also is there pcre library on macos which I can use to compile mod_security to match the one that Apache is using?

Answer (score 1):

If you have `mod_info` enabled, you can put the following into the configuration of your (virtual) host:

```
<Location /server-info>
SetHandler server-info
</Location>
```

After reloading you could visit `yoursite/server-info` and it should give comprehensive details of your server. See [the apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_info.html) for more info.

Comment: thanks, that's useful. but it still does not tell me version of pcre used in compilation, I wonder how the module knows which one was loaded.

Comment: That technically should be a separate question. Undoubtedly the library has a global variable that contains the version, so anything loading the library can check that. As it's not complaining I'd assume the library works fine, so why bother trying to get the exact match? Also I'd say 8.02 equals 8.2, it's not a decimal value, is major.minor version. If I check the changelog on my system, the versions go from 7.9 to 8.00 to 8.01 to 8.02 ... 8.19, 8.20, 8.21 ...

Comment: yeah i compiled 8.02 although it says 8.2

Comment: you're right, there's no reason for exact same match, i just think it's better to specify pcre with which apache was compiled. i found where the version comes from -- php_info() shows --with-pcre-regex=/usr and PCRE Library Version 8.02 in modules. but when i try to compile mod_secure specifying "--with-pcre=/usr", it cannot find config file.